# WebApi route doesn't work in Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an application and I have moved my admin panel to areas, since then I am unable to hit the adminpanel api calls. here is the code for main api registration and admin panel api registration.

```
    //Api registration
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Secondary",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    //Area Registration
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_panel",
            "AdminPanel/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          "Admin_Secondary",
          "AdminPanel/api/{controller}/{id}",
          new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

I am trying to hit it with URL localhost/taw/adminpanel/api/SearchAPI but it doesn't work. what's wrong with my routing?

Answer (score 7):

I found out the issue, precedence of routes was creating the problem, I think I should have [asked the duck](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html) before posting the issue.

```
      context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       "Admin_Secondary",
       "AdminPanel/api/{controller}/{id}",
       new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

has to come before

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_panel",
        "AdminPanel/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```